# Is the first theme missing from the Recapitulation of Mozart Violin Concerto No. 4 - K. 218 - Alegro?

Tags: analysis, musical-forms

I have just learnt about the Concerto Sonata Form and was trying to practice by listening to Mozart's 4th Violin Concerto K. 218.  The teacher got us started, and I just want to see if I can finish breaking it up into its main parts.

I can detect the 3 themes (2 of which are introduced in the first exposition) and the 3rd is the solo theme introduced by violinist in the 2nd exposition.

I think the Recapitulation [begins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3tK0836A8c&t=287s) (4:46) with the `solo-theme`, and I can also [detect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3tK0836A8c&t=352s) the `2nd-theme` (5:52).

But between the `solo-theme` & the `2nd-theme` I was expecting to hear the `1st-theme`.

I'm totally confused now.  The orchestra (`ripiano`) ends the `solo-theme` (5:02) with (i think) the second phrase of the `1st-theme` is that it?  And is what follows (5:11) some sort of variation on the `1st-theme`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After listening to that Mozart concerto first movement, I am also forced to conclude that **the first phrase of the exposition is entirely missing from the recapitulation before the cadenza**. This is easier to determine with a video of the concerto with scrolling sheet music, such as [this one of a Grumiaux recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n5M2vk-RUGA).

You are right that 5:02 of your Oistrakh recording quotes a later phrase in the 1st-theme.

However, due to significant harmonic differences (e.g. emphasis on the G major chord and the note C natural) and use of running 16th notes, I do not believe 5:11 (or 5:02 of the Grumiaux) is a variation on the 1st-theme (assuming the 2nd-theme starts at 0:49 of the Oistrakh).

A scholar reports in http://www.lcsproductions.net/MusicHistory/MusHistRev/Articles/MozrtCncrtFrm.html that such great variation in theme content and order in Mozart concerto first movement recapitulations is to be expected.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate the reference.  How did you find that link :-)

Comment: @hba - I found the YouTube link with a Google search for "Mozart K.218" and the other link with a Google search for "concerto first movement form".